# Get all annotations in a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, project

Is there a way to all the annotations in an Eclipse project in a single `Annotation[]`? By project I mean, in ALL of the packages in the source folder.

Comment: You don't want to include referenced libraries and/or projects?

Comment: No. I just need all of my custom Annotations, not anyone else's Annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/)

> Scannotation is a Java library that creates an annotation database from a set of .class files.

Comment: That's Good! How come I didn't know it until now :)

Comment: And even it's written by my fellow Bill. Shame on me

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Java EE 6 CDI and Weld Java SE support.
http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/WeldInJavaSE

But it's not directly for filtering classes, rather for modules management, which may be what you really need.